# According to 2 Kings 6:17 does God's heavenly host in His spiritual realm interact with and exist with the mortal realm?

Tags: angels, spiritual

> 17 And Elisha prayed, and said, Lord, I pray thee, open his eyes, that he may see. And the Lord opened the eyes of the young man; and he saw: and, behold, the mountain was full of horses and chariots of fire round about Elisha. (KJV)

Elisha had to pray to God to open the eyes of his servant to be able to see the spiritual army that was available for the battle against the Syrians.  Just as Elija had earlier told Elisha in 2 Kings 2 that if Elisha saw God's chariot take him up, then Elisha's request for double Elija's portion would be answered.

> And he said, Thou hast asked a hard thing: nevertheless, if thou see me when I am taken from thee, it shall be so unto thee; but if not, it shall not be so. 11 And it came to pass, as they still went on, and talked, that, behold, there appeared a chariot of fire, and horses of fire, and parted them both asunder; and Elijah went up by a whirlwind into heaven. 12 And Elisha saw it, and he cried, My father, my father, the chariot of Israel, and the horsemen thereof.... (2 KIngs 2:10-12, KJV)

Do mortal eyes normally see the spiritual realm?  Does God's work in the spiritual realm only happen in heaven?

Comment: Do you consider the temptation etc of Jesus and his overcoming to be not 'spiritual work'?

Comment: You are confusing the question.  All of Jesus' work in His human form was for spiritual salvation, but the question ask about God's use of His spiritual agents.

Comment: Ok, that wasn't obvious.

Comment: @Steve, better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "YES", definitely.  The OP has pointed out a perfect example of this in 2 Kings 6:17 where, occasionally, mortals are able to see the unseen spiritual realm.

There are other examples as well:

- the walls of Jericho were demolished supernaturally in Josh 6
- the words and messages of the prophets also mean that the supernatural interacts with the unseen
- Josh 10 - the sun stood still
- Judges 6 describes the dual miracle of the fleece
- 2 Kings 19:35 - the angel of the LORD kills 185,000 soldiers (Isa 37:36)
- 2 Sam 24 - the angel of the LORD kills 70,000 people, see also 1 Chron 21

There are many more.

Comment: These are excellent examples you have included for the spiritual realm of God's heavenly host interacting with the mortal realm.  And, it was only occasionally that men saw the heavenly host, or heavenly messengers / angels.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To answer the first question:

> Do mortal eyes normally see the spiritual realm?

No, mortal eyes cannot. The spiritual realm doesn't have a physical location for our physical eyes to see.  But in Bible times, God reveals to his prophets what it is like through visions in terms we can understand.

Another example is when the prophet Ezekiel received a heavenly vision marked by “brilliant light." (Ezekiel 1:​26-​28)

Comment: Welcome to BH and thanks for your contribution. Your ideas look Biblical to me but if an idea is truly Biblical one ought to be able to quote relevant passages which clearly support it. You can edit your answer. Without Bible references answers are often down-voted or deleted.

Comment: @C.Stroud thanks. Will do.

Comment: @user424874, I would not say that men cannot ever see them, as occasionally the scriptures prove that they did.  But was it normal, or usual to do so?

Comment: @Gina You asked was it "normal", so  my answer is "No mortal eyes cannot (normally see) because we are not created that way. I should have stated that more clearly. But some did in Bible times like the attendant of Elisha in special occasions when God reveals His purposes to them.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.

Answer (score 1):

The mortal eyes of humans after the Fall do not normally see the spiritual world, nor do mortal ears hear it. So, while the "heavenly host" may be active around us, we become aware of it only if we have "eyes to see and ears to hear."

However, Genesis tells us that this was not always the case. In the Garden of Eden, Adam and Eve could hear and see God:

> They heard the sound of the Lord God walking in the garden in the
> cool of the day, and the man and his wife hid themselves from the
> presence of the Lord God among the trees of the garden. 9 But the Lord
> God called to the man and said to him, “Where are you?” 10 And he
> said, “I heard the sound of you in the garden, and I was afraid,
> because I was naked, and I hid myself.”  (Gen. 3)

Beyond this, the question becomes what is "normal" for fallen humans. Many people claim to see the spiritual world, but this is beyond the scope of this discussion.

**Conclusion**: The Bible teaches that the heavenly host and other spiritual entities become visible only rarely. This does not mean they are not present, however. This is true of both good and evil "hosts of heaven." As Ephesians 6:12 teaches:

> We do not wrestle against flesh and blood, but against the rulers,
> against the authorities, against the cosmic powers over this present
> darkness, against the spiritual forces of evil in the heavenly places.

Comment: Oh, but God is invisible, i.e. He cannot be seen with the eyes. "No one has seen God at any time" John 1:18

Comment: Dan, Gen. 3:8-10 does not say anything about Adam & Eve visibly seeing God, only hearing Him.  John 1:18, before Jesus' resurrection says that no man had seen the Father but He who had descended from the Father.  So that would have included Adam, I think.  And Gen. 3:22 makes it clear that they were not immortal, only mortal even in the garden.

Comment: @Steve, keep the scripture in the time frame in which it was spoken.  John 1:18 was before Jesus' resurrection, and before He ascended to the Father.  It is not still the case that no one has seen the Father as Jesus separated out the souls from Hades after the destruction of Jerusalem in AD 70 as proved by the parable of the wedding feast in Matt. 22:1-14 - "immediately after" Matt. 24:29, IOW immediately after the city was burned, Jesus separated them out of Hades during the wedding feast - Matt. 25:31ff.  I hope to help make this point clear with this question soon.

Comment: @Gina I agree with your objection to my answer. When I said "this was not always the case" I should have clarified this this referred to my point about spiritual hearing, not spiritual seeing.  I do believe that Adam and Eve's spiritual vision was unimpaired - that they could see spiritual beings such as the "serpent" who tempted them.  But this does not mean they could see God, even though I don't rule out that God could appear in a limited visible form (as with men/angels who visited Abraham).

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate the answers here as most have grasped key elements. I wished to point out some of the implications of the scriptures that are not usually included in the preaching we hear today about God's spiritual realm.

The author of Hebrews stated at Heb. 13:2,

> Be not forgetful to entertain strangers: for thereby some have entertained angels unawares. (KJV)

> of the hospitality be not forgetful, for through this unawares certain did entertain messengers; (YLT)

We do not normally see those of God’s heavenly and spiritual host as they interact with us in this mortal realm, but they are here with us doing God’s will as God instructs them.

> Bless Jehovah, ye His messengers, Mighty in power -- doing His word, To hearken to the voice of His Word. (Psa. 103:20, YLT)

The messengers / angels who are mighty in power are the heavenly messengers who do His will.  In speaking of the children, Jesus said,

> Beware! -- ye may not despise one of these little ones, for I say to you, that their messengers in the heavens do always behold the face of my Father who is in the heavens, (Matt. 18:10, YLT)

The implication here is that we have messengers in the heavens (angels) who are assigned by our Father in heaven, and those who are assigned to the children are always facing Him.  The heavenly messengers always do the will of our Father, but we do not normally see them, or if we see them we are not aware that they are heavenly angels (Heb. 13:2).

We are not aware of the spiritual beings around us but they are here with us as evidenced from scripture of ages past.  The spiritual realm operates under the instructions delegated by God, under His control.  Those living on earth will see the results of their actions possibly in rescues, or prevention from harm, and we may realize on some level that we just narrowly escaped a harmful, possibly deathly situation.  But, we do not often think that an angel of God was helping us because our mortal eyes do not see the spiritual heavenly beings with recognition.

We also need to recognize that God’s work in His heavens is under His complete control, and that His spiritual realm is not seen by mortal eyes. When Jesus sits on His throne, He is sitting in heaven at the right hand of the Father in the spiritual realm.  Sitting on His throne means that as King He is prepared for judgment. Those actions He undertakes from His throne are before His throne in heaven and are not seen by human eyes on earth.

> 31 `And whenever the Son of Man may come in his glory, and all the holy messengers with him, then he shall sit upon a throne of his glory; 32 and gathered together before him shall be all the nations, and he shall separate them from one another, as the shepherd doth separate the sheep from the goats, (Matt. 25:31-32, YLT)

The place specified in this scripture was in heaven before His throne.  The time specified of this specific prophesy which began in Matt. 24 was after the destruction of the temple in Jerusalem which happened in AD 70.  Gathering together was the gathering of all of the souls from all of the nations out of Hades, those who had already passed from the mortal realm and were held in the prison of Hades.  They were no longer in the mortal realm, but in the grave.  This is the same prophesy Jesus gave to John in Rev. 20, after the great battle depicted in Rev. 19, the battle that destroyed the temple in Jerusalem and burned the city.

> 11 And I saw a great white throne, and Him who is sitting upon it, from whose face the earth and the heaven did flee away, and place was not found for them; 12 and I saw the dead, small and great, standing before God, and scrolls were opened, and another scroll was opened, which is that of the life, and the dead were judged out of the things written in the scrolls -- according to their works; 13 and the sea did give up those dead in it, and the death and the hades did give up the dead in them, and they were judged, each one according to their works;  (Rev. 20:11-13, YLT)

This gathering before His throne took place in heaven, in the spiritual realm.  Mortal eyes did not witness this gathering, as the place was not on the earth but in heaven before Jesus’ throne.  Therefore, no one on earth saw this gathering.  No one can say that it has not yet happened based upon these scriptures as the place of the gathering is clearly detailed to be in heaven, not here on this earth.

Stephen saw Jesus standing at the right hand of God just before he was stoned to death (Acts 7:55-56).  It may be that during those moments just before our physical body gives up our spirit that the faithful see the spiritual realm clearly as we transition and are gathered home.

I will always remember that just before my grandmother passed that she opened her eyes fully and saw someone just behind me and a little above my left shoulder.  I turned but saw no one, and as I turned back to her she breathed her last.  I am convinced she saw the angel who took her home.

God’s heavenly host are here with us, helping us and doing His will.  They interact with us in this mortal realm even though we do not see them, or are not aware of them.  The events that take place in the spiritual realm in heaven are not seen by mortal eyes. But, those that have passed on to be gathered into heaven into their eternal life are now in the presence of God, and reunited with all of their people.

Further reading:

[The Gathering of the Elect](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2017/07/30/the-gathering-of-the-elect/)

[Hades Is No More](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2022/08/25/hades-is-no-more/)

[Testing The Spirits - Part III: Daniel's Lot](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2022/02/12/testing-the-spirits-part-iii-daniels-lot/)